# Processing images without GDI+ in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image-processing, gdi+

For some reasons, I need to write few image processing functions without using GDI+. I need to be able to do the following operations on images.

- Draw some shapes on existing images (mostly rectangle with a plain background color). Regularly i do this using `Graphics.DrawImage()` function in GDI+.
- Draw texts on existing image. Regularly I do this using `Graphics.DrawString()` function in GDI+
- Save image to MemoryStream. Regularly I do this by `Image.Save(stream, imgformat)` function in GDI+
- Get image bytes. Regularly I do this by `MemoryStream.ToArray()` function. I need `bytes` because I need to be able to send image to `HttpContext()` using the `context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageBytes)` method.

I've already looked at [AForge.net](http://www.aforgenet.com/), but it is missing `Image.Save()` method. It uses native `Bitmap.Save()` method of GDI+. So I seem to have no way of surviving GDI+ with AForge.

I've also looked at OpenCV and its .NET wrapper [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), but after 2 days of hard try, I was not able to successfully integrate the project into my own project (I know this sound silly, but that is truth. Following all the tutorials, probably 20+ SO posts on this did not help, because my solution structure is a little bit more than (more complex) a regular solutions).

How can I achieve this? Show me some way please. Have you even found yourself in such a situation (situation where you need to process images, but no GDI+)? What are the other libraries that could help me?

Comment: I guess I'll ask the obvious question. Why wouldn't you utilize GDI+? Are you really going to try and represent a Bitmap in memory manually and write your own persistence mechanisms for each file type?

Comment: nice question, "GDI+ less image processing in C#", I'm interested in the answer for this question. :)

Comment: the problem is GDI+'s poor ability to keep the image quality when saving images. on the other hand, I'm tired of resolving `Generic GDI+ errors`. Instead of writing my own mechanism for image processing, probably I'll be using some .net library on this?

Comment: "Process images" doesn't mean "Save images". If saving an image is your only concern.. I would suggest you look into actually setting proper values on the encoder you use to save images. Perhaps [looking here might help you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter(v=vs.110).aspx). You can set 100% quality and use different formats to get the result you require. GDI+ doesn't just save at a single quality. If you want better.. you need to tell it.

Comment: I am absolutely agree with you. However, `Save` is still a part of image processing, and this is where most of my problems are. Each task requires me to save the image somewhere, sometimes on `temp` files, and sometimes on MemoryStream. For other small glitches, I still need to survive GDI+... still...

Comment: WPF (`BitmapSource` and friends) don't use GDI+, but Windows Imaging Component with Direct2D.  Still, you need to tell it what you want it to do - GDI works perfectly fine if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a recent project that's gathering momentum called, appropriately, "ImageProcessor": https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor - NuGet reports over 344,000 downloads as of June 2016.

Scott Hanselmann did a feature on it about 8 months ago, explaining the motivation given that .NET Core does not have System.Drawing (and I note that Windows Azure does not officially support GDI in Website Roles): http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RFCServersideImageAndGraphicsProcessingWithNETCoreAndASPNET5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just attempted to answer a similar question here:
[server-side graphics generation in .net/c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815536/server-side-graphics-generation-in-net-c/)

Adding any other vector graphics (and layout) would be quite simple as well. Let me know if you would like a sample project or code.

Comment: I don't see how this is similar at all. The OP here is asking how to manipulate images without using the built in libraries. Also, this is more a comment than an answer.